# Filter out children of a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently mapping the values of my parent components children in the following way:

```
const subRows = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
  return child;
});
```

What I want is to target these children's type values so that I can filter out specific children in the return. Anyone know if there is an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 16):

You access properties on a child via its `props`.

If you want to filter the children, you could use [`React.Children.toArray`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.toarray) to obtain a normal JS array and then use its [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
const subRows = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).filter((child, i) => {
  return child.props.someProp;
});
```

Do keep in mind that:

> `React.Children.toArray()` changes keys to preserve the semantics of nested arrays when flattening lists of children. That is, `toArray` prefixes each key in the returned array so that each element's key is scoped to the input array containing it.

You can also use [`React.Children.forEach`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.foreach) and populate an array available in the outer scope:

```
const subRows = [];
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
  if (child.props.someProp) {
    subRows.push(child)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).filter(...)
```

Comment: While this [code may answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a library to extend the React Children utilities, where there are functions for filtering and even deep filtering react components

https://fernandopasik.com/react-children-utilities/filter

```
import React from 'react';
import { filter } from 'react-children-utilities';

const Filtered = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {filter(children, (child) => child.type === 'span')}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hi, can you please check this question? related to `child.type` thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741708/when-looping-through-react-children-not-able-to-compare-child-type-with-compone